# File mysql.h can't be found

Tags: mysql

I have installed MySQL in Ubuntu 14.04 but I can't find the `mysql.h` file in any directory. I don't mean that the compiler can't find it, as mentioned in countless other questions, here but I can't find the actual file. Why is that? Where can I find it?

Comment: What's the outcome of `find / | grep mysql.h`?

Comment: try 
locate mysql.h

Comment: @Mayur that is the whole point...Obviously that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: What mysql package(s) did you install exactly? The file is part of the `libmysqlclient-dev` package

Comment: @Mitch it returns a lot of files that have myspql as part of their name but not the .h.

Comment: @steeldriver I have installed mysql-server, apache2, php5, php5-mysql. I followed instructions that said to install those packages.

Comment: @adam `locate mysql.h` is a command

Comment: @Mayur Oh I didn't understand it.  I am sorry. I used it now and it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can't find mysql.h then it probably isn't anywhere in your filesystem unless you have one of these three packages installed which provides mysql.h:

- libmariadbclient-dev - `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h`
- libmysqlclient-dev - `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h`
- pike7.8-mysql - `/usr/lib/pike7.8/7.4/include/mysql.h`

Comment: Thank you I installed the first and it the file was created.

Comment: You can search the package for a missing file with eg: `apt-file search /mysql.h`

Answer (score 0):

try
 `$ find /usr/ -name 'mysql.h'`
or
perhaps it is present at `/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h.` (Iam not sure)

Comment: I have searched in these directories according to the other answers here. The command that @Mitch proposed in the comments would have found it if it existed.